# set cookie after submit button in wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am not even sure if it is cookies I need here, perhaps there is a better method.

I currently have a page with links for downloads. To get to this page the user will have to submit their email address. I am using the plugin Contact Form 7 for the email entry. I then plan on redirecting this to the page. The plugin allows me to add IDs to the submit button.

Should I be setting a cookie here using JavaScript? I won't be able to put JavaScript into the form, but I can have the form on my own page template.

Heres the outputted html, Im reluctant to go and try and change this as its a plugin..

```
<form action="/downloads/#wpcf7-f127-p124-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">

<div style="display: none;">

<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="127" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="3.4" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f127-p124-o1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="211b6bff7f" />

</div>

<p>Your Name (required)<br />

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" /></span> </p>

<p>Your Email (required)<br />

<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" /></span> </p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>

<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
```

Comment: What would you use cookies for? I'm missing the point of what you're trying to do I Think

Comment: Well basically I want to force the user to enter an email address (for a newsletter) before a page with download links appear. I guess I thought cookies was my option here as I could check if the cookie existed when arriving on the page with downloads. If it didnt I could hide access to the links. Although Im aware that maybe cookies arent my best option

Comment: My other issue is that the form Im actually using is a plugin which I dont want to go hacking. I would rather have all the functionality on a page template file, and just use IDs that can be added to the form (within the plugin)

Comment: You won't need to edit the form in any way. Just change the `email` from my answer to the name of the email field in the form.

Comment: thanks for the help, that makes alot more sense. I'll implement this now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `$_SESSION` variable to determine whether or not the user has set an email. `Cookies` can easily be changed or removed by the user. Of course, in this case you wouldn't need to fear the latter, but you get the point. *SESSION* vars, on the other hand, are not going to be editable by any user of your application.

Example HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email here..." name="email" />
</form>
```

Example PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    // Set the session val
    $_SESSION['user_email_set'] = true;
}

// Check if user entered email

if(isset($_SESSION['user_email_set']) && $_SESSION['user_email_set']){
    // Show downloads page
}
```

Comment: Hi Evan, Im wondering is it possible you could help, because the page actually redirects the session gets lost, so as a result the `if(isset($_POST['email']))` never passes.

Comment: @Adrian Make sure you set the `SESSION` var prior to redirecting the page and it will stay. Session vars don't disappear on page redirection

Comment: @Adrian You need to find the form's template file in wordpress, it's easy trust me, and put the code there. The plugin you're referring to is very simple, I've used it before, and finding the code where it validates is as simple as following its `action` in the form itself.

Comment: do you mean the file that is creating that html yea? ok thanks ill take a look,

Comment: Hi Evan, apologies for all the questions, unfortunately I cant find where the action goes to as it seems to just go to itself (it uses the page name and and an id. When I put the code into classes.php it didnt work, it seems no matter what I do the post doesnt seem to get passed to the new page.

Comment: @Adrian See my profile and email me. I can't do this via comments on SO